# Lost 2 weeks worth of progress by clicking 'Checkout' in Xcode source control, is there any way to recover it?

Tags: swift, xcode, git

I admit that I have very little experience with source control and git, however, in my past projects it has been useful to make commitments as backups. During this project, I decided to test out making a new branch. After working in it I decided to click 'checkout' master not knowing what it really did, now all my commits 2 weeks prior have been deleted, it's like I traveled back in time and all those commits I made never existed. All the files I had been working on are now gone and nowhere to be seen. I searched trash, I searched the project folder. They vanished. Did I screw up? Is there any way to recover this files? I searched all the branches without any luck. Thanks.

Comment: And if you checkout your branch? Also have a look at the `git reflog`...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how Xcode's UI spells it, but the git command is `git checkout @{1}`.  Look up reflogs and revisions, `@{1}` is how git spells "what I had checked out just before I did whatever just changed it".

Answer (score 1):

> Did I screw up?

Not necessarily! If you made commits on the new branch, everything is still there, on the new branch you created and worked on. So just checkout that branch again, and it will return!

> now all my commits 2 weeks prior have been deleted

Ah, so you did make commits. In that case, be assured, nothing is lost.

But if you did *not* commit on the new branch — if you checked out master without committing your work from the new branch you were working on — then yes, you screwed up and it is all gone. The substance of git is commits, and whatever is not committed is not in the purview of git and is subject to unexpected loss. Loss due to checkout is a classic git trap; you would think it would warn you of the danger, but it doesn’t always do that.

Comment: I object to your last paragraph. `git checkout` does not lose content. If it's tracked but not committed, it stays in your work tree or index until you tell Git where to commit it, and if you try to check out something that would overwrite it, Git refuses with   `error: your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout`. You have options for what to do then.

Comment: @jthill I'm aware of the canard that git will stop you if it isn't safe to checkout. In my view, a beginner should be told that commit-(or-stash)-before-checkout is a rule of life.

Comment: For sufficiently new newbies, that's a good first rule, sure, but, "canard"?  I'm not going to let that pass without an objection. Git *will* stop you if it's not safe to checkout. And you have options for what to do then.

Comment: @jthill Problem is, we don't know what happened. The OP has claimed that the files are not on any branch. Also, OP is not using git at the command line, but via Xcode, whose git integration is horrendous and which might very well permit the checkout without a murmur for all I know. So while I want to be reassuring, I also don't want to overpromise; there _is_ a possibility that the files got silently overwritten or something.